# How to get cursor.forEach() iterator to wait for promise chain to resolve?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, node-mongodb-native

Using node.js `mongodb` native module I'm trying to use a promisified iterator but it is not waiting for the promise chain to resolve before firing the `finalCallback`

```
db.collection('items').find({}).forEach(promiseIterator, finalCallback);

function promiseIterator(doc){
    return Promise.resolve(doc)
        .then(res => {
            console.log(res); // this fires *after* finalCallback fires
        })
}

function finalCallback(res){
    console.log(res); // this fires *before* promiseIterator resolves all promise chains
}
```

The doc is here: https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#~resultCallback

Their ES6 examples all use generators so I'm not sure if Promises even work here. But the promise chain is not fully resolved before firing `finalCallback`.

https://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/reference/ecmascript6/crud/

The reason I'm having this issue is because my `promiseIterator` needs to make several async/promisified calls on each document. (I am unable to load all docs into memory with `.toArray()` as there are over a million documents and I get a `process out of memory` error when I try that.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you cannot. Mongodb native's forEach doesn't wait for Promises to resolve as you noticed. They just call for a callback function and continues to next object.

Cursor's `forEach` source code (line 769)

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/lib_cursor.js.html

You need to iterate manually with `next` and `hasNext`.

http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html#next

EDIT: Example added.

You can use promises exactly as jstice4all succested. Here is his example with more details.

```
db.collection('items').find({}, (err, resultCursor) => {
  resultCursor.next(processItem);

  function processItem(err, item) {
    if(item === null) return; // All done!

    // Add your asynchronous function/chain of functions in place of Promise.resolve()
    Promise.resolve().then(() => {
      resultCursor.next(processItem); // Read next item from database
    });
  }
});
```

Of course this will process all objects serially, one after another. If you want to process all objects in parallel and wait for them to finish before doing something else, you should use collect all created promises with `Promise.all`.

btw. `nextObject` is deprecated, so you can use `next` instead of it.

Comment: Can you provide example? I tried to use `yield` from their docs but I get a syntax error. I'm using node v7. Their docs don't have any Promise examples (I only see generators) yet they claim you can use them.

Comment: Where is the `externalAsyncFunction()` called from in your example?

Comment: My example was just referencing jstice4all's example which seems to be correct. Better refer that than copy example in thia

Comment: I do not get a `next` callback passed to `externalAsyncFunction`

Comment: I combined jstice4all's example with my example. It should be clear now.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a recursion with `nextObject` instead of `forEach`:

```
db.collection('items').find({}, function(err, resultCursor) {
  function processItem(err, item) {
    if(item === null) {
      return; // All done!
    }

    externalAsyncFunction(item, function(err) {
      resultCursor.nextObject(processItem);
    });

  }

  resultCursor.nextObject(processItem);
}
```

Comment: Is it possible to use promises here with `nextObject`?

Comment: Yes, just call `nextObject` from `then`.

Comment: Would you mind adding an example that uses promises with `.find()` and cursor instead of callbacks. I think this is the correct answer but I want to use promises.